# Concatenating two columns in ArcGIS 10.2.1: "no records within table"?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, text, table-of-contents, concatenation

I am trying to merge two text columns (consisting of 2 digit and 3 digit numbers respectively) into one in ArcGIS 10.2.1 desktop version, but unable to do so. I have added a new field and kept it as text. On using arc toolbox > data management tools > calculate field, I am trying to merge the two columns into the newly created column.

Example:

I have the following two columns in the shapefile - Code1 (text, 10) and Code 2 (text, 10). I want to concatenate the values in these two columns in a new data field **Key** (text,11) that I have already created.

```
Code1 Code2  Key                                                                         
015   21     21015                                                                                    
647   19     19647                                                                               
213   05     05213
```

When I try to use field calculator I get the error `no records within table`. See below:

[image]

Comment: What output do you get? Could you post an image of your Field Calculator window? What are the field lengths of each of the three text fields?

Comment: hi, the length of each field is 10 and its Data Type is Text. Also the output is blank in the desired field. The error message says - No records within table.

Comment: Use python parser and: `!RMSCODE2!+!RMSCODE1!`

Answer (score 1):

General answer (may update based on poster's details of what they've tried):

Change the Parser in the Field Calculator to "Python".

For the field calculation, double click the fields you want to add, separating them by a plus sign. (Plus sign is also used when concatentating strings).

The example code would be:

```
!field1! + !field2!
```

Edit: Question was updated to include error message "No records within table". This is possibly due to extent in the environment settings per [ArcGIS Calculate Fields gives Warning 000405 No records within table?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/136650/arcgis-calculate-fields-gives-warning-000405-no-records-within-table)

Answer (score 1):

Check if extent from spatial data has been set and if data being concatenated is extrapolating it. See: [ArcGIS Calculate Fields gives Warning 000405 No records within table?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/136650/arcgis-calculate-fields-gives-warning-000405-no-records-within-table).

---

In field calculator, two options to concatenate fields exist: using VB parser or Python parser.

- VB parser: `[Field1] & [Field2]`
- Python parser: see [smiller's answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/285925/concatenating-two-columns-in-arcgis-10-2-1-no-records-within-table/285929#285929).

Comment: hi.. thank you for replying, but still getting the same error. the error message is - No records within table

Comment: than export everything in excel sheet, do whatever you want, and joins two tables to get your field.

Answer (score -1):

You can also do it with OGRINFO and OGR2OGR GDAL

Comment: GeospatialEngineer, please expand upon your answer.