Field Calculating in ArcMap edit session


I'm trying to update the field in yellow using field calculator in ArcMap in an editing session. It is a numeric field and I'm updating with  a number. I just type 1.
However, I am getting the error message below.
Could anyone advise?
If I try to edit manually, I get this message:

Could anyone advise?

Is the file read-only?

The calculated value didn't fit your field (like string in a numeric field or a too long string for your field or...) check that the result for your expression always match the destination field

@J.R the DAZone field is a numeric field of 'short integer' and i entered a number (1).  It still doesnt work

Please always provide error messages as formatted text and not only in pictures.

Short integer are short so it's easy to input a to big number (I learn it the hard way with postcode...)

Set environment extent to cover your polygons. For me such behavior is a bug, but is a reality

https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/136650/arcgis-calculate-fields-gives-warning-000405-no-records-within-table

Few things to try:

Create a new test field(integer) and try populating it, this will rule out if the issue specific to a field
Is the issue specific to this layer? Does any other layers tend to reproduce this? I mean any other layer with short int data type you can test with.
Try exporting the layer and test the calculate on that new layer https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/map/working-with-layers/exporting-features.htm
Check if there's a conflict with editing if its involving SDE
By any chance you have ArcGIS Pro to test this out? You might hit the exact cause of this issue while trying to edit

Last but not the least, It would be good to trace what is the data source of this layer? Was it downloaded from some 3rd party website? Created manually? Or if its ok to share it with us for debugging?
